# Interpretation of coxph - rsq , cox.zhp, robust and concordance

Tags: r, survival, likelihood, cox-model

I would like to get explained the following situations in coxph (`library(survival)`)

1. The Concordance, what is a good Concordance?
2. What does it mean `robust= 2.61 p=0.1` in a `logrank  p=0.006` ?
3. what is a good rsq? `(summary(coxph.model) $ rsq`
4. How to interpret `cox.zph (coxph.model)` -  the output has, for every variable in the multivariable coxph.model a `chisq`, `df` and `p value`. Also, in addition to the variables in the multivariable model, there is a GLOBAL value.

This would be a potential output (I've tricked the name of the variables due to confidenciality) - I think it would be helpful to have the interpretation of this particular output as a guidance, if possible.

[image]

thank you!

Comment: The vignettes in the R `survival` package (the package you are using without stating it) are freely available and are truly excellent.  Note that the Cox model is not a multivariate (multiple dependent variables) model but is a multivariable (multiple predictors) model.

Comment: For item 2, it would help to see the actual model and the summary results from which you selected those values. One expects p-values to differ between robust and other estimates, but that seems like a pretty big difference.

Comment: I hope is now more clear. Thank you for your contributions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Point 1.* Quoting from Section 20.10 of Frank Harrell's [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rms/):

> The *c* index [concordance] is the proportion of all pairs of subjects whose survival time can be ordered such that the subject with the higher predicted survival is the one who survived longer.

So a concordance of 0.5 is what you get if a model can't distinguish survival times at all. What's "good" above that depends on the nature of the study.

*Point 2.* Standard significance tests assume that observations are independent. Your use of an `id` variable indicates that some individuals (or groups of individuals with the same `id` value) contributed to multiple observations. Perhaps a single individual could experience more than 1 event. The "robust" standard error estimate takes that lack of independence into account, generally leading to wider confidence intervals and higher p-values. As the output from the summary says:

> The likelihood ratio and score [logrank] tests assume independence of observations within a cluster, the Wald and robust score tests do not.

Point 3. See the answer to Point 1. What's good depends on the nature of the study. I find concordance and measures of model validation and calibration to be more useful than $R^2$ values. I strongly recommend learning to use the tools in Frank Harrell's [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) to evaluate model quality.

Point 4. This is covered at the end of Chapter 3 (Section 3.5.2, "Score tests") of the main [survival vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/survival.pdf).

> The `cox.zph` function checks proportional hazards for a fitted Cox model directly...

for individual predictors or for the model as a whole (GLOBAL). A low p-value indicates evidence against PH. In your case, it looks like `age` might violate PH. You might fix that by modeling age flexibly with a spline (e.g., `rcs()` in the `rms` package), as incorrect specification of the functional form of a continuous predictor can show up as an apparent violation of PH.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer. I have only one question regarding point 2, though: In the univariable model, should I then take the p value from the Robust (p=0.1) rather than the one from the logrank (p=0.006) and assume that there is no difference between var1 high and var1 low? - sorry if I maybe missunderstood. thanks!

Comment: @Lili if you had multiple events for the same `id` value (which seems to be the case), then you need to use the robust estimate. That said, a uni-variable Cox model is not very reliable, as it doesn't take other outcome-associated predictors into account. The results of your multi-variable model suggest that much of what might have appeared (nearly) "significant" about `var1` in the first model was due to its associations with sex, age, or BMI. That's not the same as "no difference" associated with `var1` itself, just that you can't _show_ there's a difference with these data.

Comment: gotcha! - thanks so much!